# How do you compute (hyper) Ext for two chain complexes?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, derived-functors

I've asked a version of this question on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/431216/148766), so here's a hyperlink for continuity. If I get an answer on one, I can CW the other (or, you can answer both )

---

Let $C_{\bullet}$ and $D_{\bullet}$ be chain complexes of $R$-modules for a ring $R$, and let $M$ be an $R$-module.

It's known how to compute $\mathrm{Ext}_{R}^{*}(C_{\bullet},M)$; namely, there is a convergent Grothendieck spectral sequence whose second page is
\begin{align*}
E_{2}^{pq}=\mathrm{Ext}_{R}^{p}(h_{q}(C_{\bullet}),M)\Rightarrow\mathrm{Ext}_{R}^{p+q}(C_{\bullet},M).
\end{align*}
See, for instance, (13.8.2) in Remark 38 in [these notes](http://www.math.boun.edu.tr/instructors/wdgillam/deftheory.pdf).

My question is what can be said when we replace $M$ with another complex $D_{\bullet}$.

Elaborating based on the comments: I am already familiar with spectral sequences that compute Tor; supposing $C_{\bullet}$ and $D_{\bullet}$ are bounded below:
\begin{align*}
^{II}E_{pq}^{2}&&=&&\bigoplus_{q'+q''=q}\mathrm{Tor}^R_{p}(h_{q'}(C_{\bullet}),h_{q''}(D_{\bullet}))&&\Rightarrow&&\mathrm{Tor}_{p+q}^{R}(C_{\bullet},D_{\bullet})\\
^{I}E_{pq}^{2}&&=&&h_{p}\mathrm{Tot}^{\oplus}\mathrm{Tor}_{q}(C_{\bullet},D_{\bullet})&&\Rightarrow&&\mathrm{Tor}_{p+q}^{R}(C_{\bullet},D_{\bullet}).
\end{align*}

This comes from (5.7.5) in Weibel's *An introduction to homological algebra*. I would like to know the analogous statement for Ext, which Weibel skips.

In the particular case I care about, $C_{\bullet}$ is bounded below by $0$ (i.e., $C_{i}=0$ for $i<0$) and $D_{\bullet}$ is bounded -- specifically, $D_{j}=0$ for $j\not\in\{0,1\}$. Using a spectral sequence to compute explicitly even the first two or three Ext groups in this case would be fantastic.

If the general argument is well-known, please point me to it; otherwise for now I am happy to learn how to compute $\mathrm{Ext}_{R}^{n}(C_{\bullet},D_{\bullet})$ in terms of the homologies $h_{i}(C_{\bullet})$ and $h_{j}(D_{\bullet})$, even just for $n=0,1,2$.

---

**EDIT**: My suspicion/expectation is that the two spectral sequences are
\begin{align*}
^{II}E^{pq}_{2}&&=&&\bigoplus_{q'+q''=q}\mathrm{Ext}_R^{p}(h_{q'}(C_{\bullet}),h_{q''}(D_{\bullet}))&&\Rightarrow&&\mathrm{Ext}^{p+q}_{R}(C_{\bullet},D_{\bullet})\\
^{I}E^{pq}_{2}&&=&&h_{p}\mathrm{Tot}^{\prod}\mathrm{Ext}^{q}(C_{\bullet},D_{\bullet})&&\Rightarrow&&\mathrm{Ext}^{p+q}_{R}(C_{\bullet},D_{\bullet}),
\end{align*}
but (1) I do not know if this is correct, and (2) I am having a bit of trouble tracking the low-index convergence to calculate $\mathrm{Ext}^{0}_{R}(C_{\bullet},D_{\bullet})$, $\mathrm{Ext}^{1}_{R}(C_{\bullet},D_{\bullet})$, and $\mathrm{Ext}^{2}_{R}(C_{\bullet},D_{\bullet})$ for the aforementioned bounded below $C_{\bullet}$ and bounded $D_{\bullet}$.

Comment: There is an «hyper-Ext» spectral sequence, just as there an «hyper-Tor» one. This should ne in Weibel's book, or in EGA somehwere.

Comment: Thanks @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez! I have Weibel's book; do you happen to know the chapter and verse?

Comment: I am sure it has a section with "hypercohomology" in the title!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez that section goes into some detail for hyper Tor and even gives a hyper Tor spectral sequence, but I believe it skips hyper Ext and only in passing mentions right hyper-derived functors at all with one application, hypercohomology itself. I guess the core of my question is exactly what Weibel has skipped: (1) what, explicitly, is the spectral sequence for hyper Ext? (2) how does it degenerate when $C_{\bullet}$ is bounded below and $D_{\bullet}$ is supported in $[0,1]$? Can the convergence statements be turned into an explicit isom. of $Ext^{n}(C_{\bullet},D_{\bullet})$?

Comment: I don't rememeber if that is trated in detail anywhere, but for bounded complexes it should be just the same as for hypertor. Consider it as a long exercise! The spectral sequence will not degenerate in that case (why would it?)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez it has already been a long exercise for me, so I suppose my post is asking someone to graciously give me a bit more assistance -- I'm really only asking for the statement of the spectral sequence, not even its proof. (To use Weibel's notation: what are the $\phantom{x}^{I}E_{2}^{pq}$ and $\phantom{x}^{II}E_{2}^{pq}$ converging (hopefully) to $Ext^{p+q}(C_{\bullet},D_{\bullet})$.) Thanks nonetheless; I appreciate the comments!